# Why Does Instragram Not Run One Of My Text Animations Properly When I Open the Link In My Profile?

Tags: html, css

So I recently added some text animations to my personal website and everything seems to be working fine. However, I went on to my Instagram profile and tried opening the link from my bio and the words 'Florida State University' is partially off the page and I cannot seem to figure out why. You can only see this if you go onto my Instagram profile and click the link from there. Would this be an issue on Instagram's part or is there something wrong with the code that I made?

Instagram: @julian31sanchez

My Website: [julianwsanchez.com](https://julianwsanchez.com/)

How it looks when I open the link from my Instagram bio: [Insta Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggzJf.jpg)

My Code:

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #141414;
    transition: 3s;
}

svg {
    display: inline-flex;
    font: 4em 'Montserrat';
    
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-copy {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 6% 29%;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
    animation: stroke-offset 5.5s infinite linear;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(1){
    stroke: #CEB888;
    animation-delay: -1;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(2){
    stroke: #782F40;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(3){
    stroke: #ffffff ;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(4){
    stroke: #782F40;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

.text-copy:nth-child(5){
    stroke: #CEB888;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}

@keyframes stroke-offset{
    100% {stroke-dashoffset: -35%;}
}



button{
    margin: 7px auto;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1{
    
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-weight: 700;
    
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

    text-shadow:
        0.05em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, .75),
        -0.025em -.05em 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, .75),
        0.025em 0.05em 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, .75);

    animation: h1 2000ms infinite;
}

@keyframes h1{
    0%{
        text-shadow:
        0.05em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, .75),
        -0.05em -.025em 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, .75),
        -0.025em 0.05em 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, .75);
    }
    15%{
        text-shadow:
        -0.05em -0.025 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, .75),
        0.025em 0.025em 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, .75),
        -0.05em 0.05em 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, .75);
    }
    50%{
        text-shadow:
        0.025em 0.05em 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, .75),
        0.05em 0 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, .75),
        0 -0.05em 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, .75);
    }
    100%{
        text-shadow:
        -0.025em 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, .75),
        -0.025em -0.025em 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, .75),
        -0.025em -0.05em 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, .75);
    }
}

h2{
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

h3{
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -4.5em;
}
button{
    background-color: #141414;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    width: 450px;
    height: 70px;
    border: .1px solid #32ff7e;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: transform .6s;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
button:hover{
    color:#32ff7e;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   li {
     width: 90%;
   }
  button{
    width: 100%;
  }
  svg{
      width: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
    <title>Julian Sanchez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    
    
    .button__text{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .button__icon{
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>



    
    <h1>Hey I'm Julian </h1>
    <h2>
        I'm an incoming CS student at<br>
         
        <span>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 960 300">
                <symbol id="s-text">
                    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="30%">Florida State University</text>
                </symbol>
            
                <g class = "g-ants">
                    <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
                    <use xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </span><br>
    </h2>
    <h3>    
    I enjoy creating small projects, such<br>
        as this website!
    </h3>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="btn">
            <ul>
            <li>
                <form>   
                <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.linkedin.com/in/julian-sanchez-920262235/">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">LinkedIn</span>
                </button>
                </form>    
            </li>
                   
            <li>
                <form>
                <button type="submit" formaction="mailto:julian31sanchezz@gmail.com">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Email</span>
                </button>
            </form>
                </li>    
                
                <li>
                    <form>
                    <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.instagram.com/julian31sanchez/">
                
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Instagram</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form>
                    <button type="submit" formaction="https://twitter.com/julian31sanchez">
                    
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Twitter</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </li>

                <li>
                    <form>
                    <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100079338796074">
                    
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Facebook</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                </li>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form>
                <button type="submit" formaction="https://t.snapchat.com/JH4olhF8">
                    
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-snapchat"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Snapchat</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form>
                    <button type="submit" formaction="https://github.com/julian31sanchez">
                    
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">GitHub</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form>
                    <button type="submit" formaction="https://discord.com/users/529387234722447403">    
                        
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
                            <span class="button__text">Discord</span>
                        </button>    
                    </form>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What phone do you have? it seems to work for me maybe try updating instagram [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npRjQ.png)

Comment: That's really weird. I am using the iPhone Xs and my Instagram is up to date. I have no idea why I am seeing it differently. Does the problem have to do with my phone?

Comment: it could be because of instagram's in app browser that is messing it up or try changing the iphone font size in settings